# locating visible elements

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Is there any way to locate just visible elements with Watir?

I want to locate only visible forms (by the index param) so that Watir would return first or second visible text field.

How is it possible to filter invisible fields / elements?
Is it possible to do that with xpath?

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML.

Answer (score 5):

This will return the first visible text field:

```
browser.text_fields.select {|text_field| text_field.visible?}[0]
```

You can set text in text field like this:

```
browser.text_fields.select {|text_field| text_field.visible?}[0].set "text"
```

This will return the second visible text field:

```
browser.text_fields.select {|text_field| text_field.visible?}[1]
```

Please note that element can be visible, but disabled.

Comment: You can shorten it a bit by using `select`, as it would not require the `compact`. This should be equivalent `browser.text_fields.select{|text_field| text_field.visible?}`

Comment: Thanks @JustinKo, I have edited my answer to use `select` instead of `collect`. Feel free to edit answers in the future.

Comment: You can shorten it even more: `browser.text_fields.select(&:visible?)[0]`